# Long Horizontal submenu

Tags: menu, tabs, contextual-menu

So there is a challenge, lets say we have a selection and sub-selection, when few items in sub-selection menu it looks great(image 1), but problem occurs when many ( image 2 )

I drafted solution in image 2, but I think its not good at all

**Remark**: - changing to vertical menu is not an option - scrolling sub-items is not a solution either

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: Best practices for tabs that exceed the viewport width is to make them scroll horizontally (it's also the easiest way to maintain and code). If you're against it and also against vertical tabs I think what you did in **Image 2** is probably the only option left. It will be a nightmare to code it, though, but I can't think of any other option (well, in fact I can and I have seen it before but it looks horrible and it's too confusing: to have 2 rows of  tabs)

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid "tabs in tabs". Is there a reason why all of the sub-tabs need to be visible to the user? If so, the usual pattern is a vertical sub-menu on the right. Curious why that wouldn't be an option?

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but content of this "Lore ipsums" is usually a data table in 98% or cases across platform is section and subsection with very few options, but these 2% are like example provided above that drives me craze, another reason not to use left menu is that website already has left menu outside of this sections.

Comment: Another simple option to code can be to add a second row of sub-tabs when they don't fit in one row.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is a well-designed **mega menu** with subitems:

[image]

<sub>*Source [designmodo.com/create-css3-mega-menu](https://designmodo.com/create-css3-mega-menu/)*</sub>

A real example is the Mailchimp > Resources megamenu with more than 20 submenus:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem may appear even with fewer tabs but in smaller viewports. I think one option which you've shared is a good one. But instead of a dropdown, you can add scroll arrows that may appear on both left and right side of the tab-bar.

[image]

**2nd option (similar to the one you shared)**
[image]
[image]

Comment: +1. first one is the way to go, but OP specifically said he doesn't want it. Second option is what he has, but it will create additional issues. Also, dropdowns should be used for content that can be grouped in some kind of logic, but if this is dynamic content, how will the system discern which link is more important and how to avoid hiding an important item while showing a less important item?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, looks like ill have to stick to my own solution, will update if something new comes up.